# convert strings in list to numbers in racket?

Tags: lisp, racket

Calling all racket developers, I am a newbie to racket language and function languages in general. Long story short, I have a nested list that contains numbers and string and I want to convert string elements to numbers.

Example: If I have list like this 
`'( 3 "3"( 1 "1"()( 2 "2" () ()))( 5 "5" () () ))`

---

I want to converted to  `'( 3 3( 1 1()( 2 2 () ()))( 5 5 () () ))`

---

While maintaining the same shape, therefore I wrote this function

```
(define (mapBst BST someFunct )
 (if (null? BST) '()
      (someFunct (car(cdr BST)) (mapBST someFunct (cdr (car BST))))
      )
  )
(mapBst  '( 3 "3"( 1 "1"()( 2 "2" () ()))( 5 "5" () () )) string->number)
```

But I am getting this error : **cdr: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: 3**

Any clue why I am getting this error or what I did wrong, any suggestions will help. Thank you in advance

Comment: you defined function `mapBST` and called with `mapBst`.

Comment: @ymonad thanks for heads up i fixed typo but still not working check i update question above

Comment: that error derives from `(cdr (car BST)))` where `(car BST)` is `3` and calling `(cdr 3)` is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest this:

```
(define (mapBST BST someFunct)
  (cond [(null? BST)
         '()]
        [(list? (car BST))
         (cons (mapBST (car BST) someFunct)
               (mapBST (cdr BST) someFunct))]
        [else
         (cons (someFunct (car BST))
               (mapBST (cdr BST) someFunct))]))
```

Example:

```
> (mapBST '( 3 "3"( 1 "1"()( 2 "2" () ()))( 5 "5" () () ))
          (λ (x) (if (string? x) (string->number x) x)))
'(3 3 (1 1 () (2 2 () ())) (5 5 () ()))
```

Comment: i wonder if `(λ (x) (if (string? x) (string->number x) x)))` logic can go somewhere inside mapBST so method call looks clean `(mapBst  '( 3 "3"( 1 "1"()( 2 "2" () ()))( 5 "5" () () )) string->number)`

Comment: @kero Sure. Change the `else` to `(string? (car BST))`, then add a new `else` case whose result is `(cons (car BST) (mapBST (cdr BST) someFunct))`.